# Changing properties of child objects(called at the same time) in a sequence action after one of actions has been completed in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

The idea of the system is when a user clicks a texture it will move to the icon which is an `ImageButton`.

I have a method `transitionTextureToActor()`.
If a user clicks the texture this method is called.

This method just changes properties of the `Image` so this `Image` will duplicate a texture and it moves to the icon which is `ImageButton`. After action of movement and sizing is completed the `Image` is supposed to become invisible.

```
private void transitionTextureToActor(ShapeProcessor shapeProcessor, Image icon) {
    tempActor = shapeProcessor.getAnimatedImage();
    tempActor.setSize(shapeProcessor.getWidth(), shapeProcessor.getHeight());
    tempActor.setPosition(shapeProcessor.getX(), shapeProcessor.getY());
    tempActor.setVisible(true);
    shapeProcessor.setVisible(false);

    tempActor.addAction(
            sequence(
                    parallel(
                            sizeTo(icon.getDrawable().getMinWidth(), icon.getDrawable().getMinHeight(), .3F),
                            moveTo(icon.getX(), icon.getY(), .3f)
                    ),
                    run(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tempActor.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    })
            )
    );
}
```

So it works well for a single call of `transitionTextureToActor` method.
After resizing and movement the image disappears.

But when I call several objects of `ShapeProcessor` at the same time only first one disappears.

```
  for(ShapeProcessor shape: shapes){
        transitionTextureToActor(shape);
    }
```

I want all of them to be invisible. Must be something wrong with `RunnableAction` because there the image becomes invisible but I can't work out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because at the time, `run()` methods of `RunnableActions` are called, they all point at the same object, referenced by `tempActor`. Try creating local references and pass them to `RunnableActions`:

```
private void transitionTextureToActor(ShapeProcessor shapeProcessor, Image iconClicked) {
    tempActor = shapeProcessor.getAnimatedImage();
    tempActor.setSize(shapeProcessor.getWidth(), shapeProcessor.getHeight());
    tempActor.setPosition(shapeProcessor.getX(), shapeProcessor.getY());
    tempActor.setVisible(true);
    shapeProcessor.setVisible(false);

    final Actor localReference = tempActor;

    tempActor.addAction(
            sequence(
                    parallel(
                            sizeTo(iconClicked.getDrawable().getMinWidth(), iconClicked.getDrawable().getMinHeight(), .3F),
                            moveTo(iconClicked.getX(), iconClicked.getY(), .3f)
                    ),
                    run(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            localReference.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    })
            )
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes .It worked. Thank you. Unfortunately I can not cast a positive vote for you because of  the beginner's reputation.

Comment: Sure, no problem, but you can consider accepting the answer though, if it was helpful.